# Samba share performance differs from Windows/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, samba, android

I have an ubuntu 14.04 installation with a samba share. Accessing the share from Windows works totally fine - I can watch movies and copy them with around 70MB/sec.

However from android devices (a media box (via ethernet) and my smartphone (wiki)) it's different. Video stutters and buffers all the time.

I tried to create a share on my Windows pc and copied one video into it. Interestingly both android devices could play this video perfectly fine from the windows share but both stutter when playing it from the ubuntu samba share.

Any ideas what could be the cause?